# make another _app.tsx file in dashboard folder under pages folder for where I use a common layout for all dashboard pages

Tags: layout, next.js, dashboard

Next.js folder structure:

[image: next.js folder structure]

I want to create a `dashboard` folder under my `pages` folder. Inside that every page will have a fixed dashboard structure. So I want to make a file like `_app` inside `dashboard` folder where I will provide my layout so that I can have every page under dashboard to have same layout.

How can I make this?

Comment: Next.js doesn't support that currently, but you could look into the per-page layout pattern described in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts.